# iPhone Text Field Only One Input Type

Tags: iphone, textfield

I have some text fields on my project.

I want that input types of text fields are only one type. For example credit card number text field's input must be only decimals and user enter another type character, it will remove or not accept in the text field.

Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can declare like the below and use

```
#define LEGAL   @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "


// allow only legal letters
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:LEGAL] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

and we can use like this also

```
entryField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: in textField's delegate, returning YES or NO for any change. You can analyze replacementString for forbidden characters and reject it if they are found.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. But it is working only after entered inputs and done from keyboard.

I want that when user began enter inputs, if user enter a forbidden character it automatically rejected.

Comment: @mozkarakoc I don't understand your comment. That method is executed before the text suffer any changes. Each time the user try to input a char it will be invoked and you can reject that char.

Comment: Probably, I don't understand how can I check forbidden characters in  " textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString". Could you give an example code or more detailed source ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the `UITextField` by code, then you need to set as follows:

textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

Comment: That is not a good solution as user can copy/paste any string on the text field.

Comment: Yes, I create a text field by code and I change keyboard type with DecimalPad. But now, i don't add a return key for DecimalPad.